# "Could not save the list changes to the server" error in SharePoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, error, custom-form

I am trying to create custom new/edit forms in SharePoint online site which was working last week.

But now it shows this error:

[image]

Tried these solutions:

1. Deleted website cache related to designer.
2. Uninstalled designer and installed SharePoint Online components.
3. There are no special characters in site name or list name.
4. Checked to disable "e374875e-06b6-11e0-b0fa-57f5dfd72085" feature. But it doesn't exists.
5. Also checked permissions. I have full control permissions on the site.

Kindly help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

Check all lookup columns if all are hooking on existing fields/lists.

More information:
https://drewmadelung.com/sharepoint-designer-error-could-not-save-the-list-changes-to-the-server/

Comment: Hello, our site doesn't have any lookup columns. And, it was working last week for the same list all of a sudden it stopped working.

Comment: You can refer to this similar situation below:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/98a582da-e9e7-4753-b2db-637ceb8ce3f6/sharepoint-could-not-save-the-list-changes-to-the-server?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by updating the alternate access mappings.

I included `{protocol}://{servername}.{domain}.{tl}`  and `{protocol}://{servername}`.